# Using powerShell to select all values that matches Unique String

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have the following file (below). I want to be able to select the unique RuleName (Safe_ports or AzureDomains), ACLType (port or dstdomain) and only grab the Rule to each Unique rule name into an array and pass it to a command.

```
**Eg:  (goal)** 

    RuleName         ACLType      Rule
    --------         -------      ----
   Safe_ports        port        21,443,22
   AzureDomains    dstdomain    .microsoft.com,.azure.com,.windows.net
```

============================================================

```
**Data source:**

RuleName         ACLType      Rule
--------         -------      ----
Safe_ports        port        21
Safe_ports        port        443
Safe_ports        port        22
AzureDomains    dstdomain    .microsoft.com
AzureDomains    dstdomain    .azure.com
AzureDomains    dstdomain    .windows.net
```

My main goal:

I want to be able to select all Rules and Unique rule name where ACLType is ports into an array.

```
# Get Azure Firewall info
$Azfw = Get-AzFirewall -Name $FirewallName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
if (!$Azfw) {
    throw "No target Azure Firewall resource is not found"
}
else {
    Write-Output "`nFirewall Name - $($Azfw.Name)"
}

#$DebugPreference = "Stop"

$netcolname = $Azfw.NetworkRuleCollections.Rules.Name

$newrules = @()
$oldrules = @()

# Get current rules and pass it back
$oldrules += $Azfw.NetworkRuleCollections.Rules

if ($Null -eq $oldrules) {
  $oldrules = $null
}

$oldrules

foreach ($name in $RuleNames) {
    if ($netcolname -match $name) {
        Write-Output "$netcolname matches - $name" 


    }
    else {
        "$name Name does not match - $netcolname"

        # Combine old rules and new rules as ONE
        $newrules = $newrules + $oldrules
        $newrules += New-AzFirewallNetworkRule -Name "$name" -Protocol TCP -SourceAddress * `
            -DestinationAddress * -DestinationPort $ports

        $newrules

        # Apply array of all rules as one
        $NetRuleCollection = New-AzFirewallNetworkRuleCollection -Name RCNet01 -Priority 200 `
            -Rule $newrules -ActionType "Allow"        

        $Azfw.NetworkRuleCollections = $NetRuleCollection

        Set-AzFirewall -AzureFirewall $Azfw
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really get exactly what you want to achieve with your code, but to come from your source data to your "goal" is quite easy

```
@'
RuleName,ACLType,Rule
Safe_ports,port,21
Safe_ports,port,443
Safe_ports,port,22
AzureDomains,dstdomain,.microsoft.com
AzureDomains,dstdomain,.azure.com
AzureDomains,dstdomain,.windows.net
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' |
    Group-Object -Property RuleName |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                RuleName = $_.Name
                ACLType = $_.Group.ACLType | Select-Object -Unique
                Rule = $_.Group.Rule -join ','
            }
        }
```